# Increasing font and icon sizes using the Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I am using https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/. I want to enlarge the font size used to display street/road names, as well as enlarge the icons. How can I do this programmatically?

I found the road's text/icon weight field in the [style reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#stylers), but modifying this does not increase the size. Which formatting option should I be using to modify the font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, font size is not supported in custom styling of Google Maps APIs.

The official documentation clearly states

> The following style options are supported:
>
> - **hue** (an RGB hex string of format #RRGGBB) indicates the basic color.
> - **lightness** (a floating point value between -100 and 100) indicates the percentage change in brightness of the element.
> - **saturation** (a floating point value between -100 and 100) indicates the percentage change in intensity of the basic color to apply to the element.
> - **gamma** (a floating point value between 0.01 and 10.0, where 1.0 applies no correction) indicates the amount of gamma correction to apply to the element.
> - **invert_lightness** (if true) inverts the existing lightness.
> - **visibility** (on, off, or simplified) indicates whether and how the element appears on the map.
> - **color** (an RGB hex string of format #RRGGBB) sets the color of the feature.
> - **weight** (an integer value, greater than or equal to zero) sets the weight of the feature, in pixels.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#stylers

In my opinion this is intentional, because increased font sizes may easily break the appearance of the map.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to enlarge street names font size in static Google Map images combining the parameters "scale" and "size".
For example, to get a static map with well readable fonts in my iPhone and Android apps, I use size=300x300 and scale=4.

Detailed explanation (see section "Scale values"):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide

Example (this static map has fonts with a right size on smartphones with hi-density screens):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&center=Piazza%20Venezia%2C%20Piazza%20Venezia%2C%20Roma%2C%20Italia&maptype=hybrid&format=png&scale=4&zoom=18&markers=Piazza%20Venezia%2C%20Piazza%20Venezia%2C%20Roma%2C%20Italia&key=YOUR_KEY
```